# Is there a Java ConfigurationBuilder() for Azure?

Tags: azure-configuration

Is there an equivalent Builder object for Java?

This code is meant for C#.   Does anyone know where the source code is so I can build a Java version of this?

```
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile("secret.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Would be easier if there was such a think so I don't need to do this:

```
protected String readPropertyFromLocalConfig(String propertyName) {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("local.settings.json)) {
        String data = IOUtils.toString(fis, ENCODING);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
            return (String)((JSONObject)jsonObject.get("Values")).get(propertyName);
        } catch (JSONException err){
            log.error("Error reading file", err.toString());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return StringUtil.EMPTY_STRING;
}
```